# Настройка программно RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-relativelayout

У меня есть CardView

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user_picture"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/user_message"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
```

В силу особенности кода мне надо передвинуть его влево в XML Это строка

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

Но мне нужно это сделать программно, но как это сделать, никак не могу найти

Comment: не советую использовать RelativeLayout. лучше ConstraintLayout

Comment: @Cypher на каком основнании?

Comment: @Tony глупый вопрос https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/android-interview-questions/differences-between-constraintlayout-relativelayout/

Comment: @Cypher ну я с вами не согласен. Считаю что Relative Layout имеет место быть и он очень просто в понимании и использовании.

Comment: @Tony гугл с вами не согласен https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Comment: @Cypher вы очень дерзко общаетесь) Умерьте свой чсв

Comment: @Tony что то вы не по теме. вот выдержка: It's similar to RelativeLayout in that all views are laid out according to relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, but it's more flexible than RelativeLayout and easier to use with Android Studio's Layout Editor.

Comment: @Cypher если не секрет вы в редакторе макеты делаете или в xml разметке ручками верстаете?

Comment: @Tony ручками. это очень просто с ConstraintLayout

Comment: @Cypher спасибо за диалог) Хорошего вечера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        val params = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END)
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM)
        cardview.layoutParams = params
```

В первой строчке укажите параметры вашего контейнера где находится CardView